# How to write PHPDoc for parameters not specifically specified in the function declaration

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

If I have a parameter I am accessing like this

`$msg = Input.get("message");`

Do I use a @param tag too, or is that only for parameters like

`public function stageFiles($user, $project)`

Also, what is the correct way to document when you return a json object.

Thanks.

Comment: `@param` is only for function (method) parameters

Comment: Use `@var` for non function variables (parameters).

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not a recognized PHP datatype, so you should use either string or stdClass depending on the actual way the JSON is being represented by that $msg variable.

If you are wanting to document a datatype for $msg, there is an informal syntax that some IDEs will recognize:

```
/** @var string $msg a JSON string */
$msg = Input . get("message");
```

Again, this is an informal syntax that *some* IDEs will recognize.  I think some IDEs look for the datatype to come after the variable name instead:

```
/** @var $msg string a JSON string */
```

Neither is considered "standard" usage, but the first one has been proposed to become standardized in PHP-FIG's PSR-5 draft.  I suggest using it, and only use the second syntax if your IDE likes it better.